# Autofill Destination from Active Dynamic Selection to certain cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the following codes to select the last 3 rows (dynamic position) in fixed columns of so that I can extrapolate till cell `Q37`.

[selection of last 3 rows in column Q R and S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUR0N.jpg)

```
Sheets("Data").Select
LastRow = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Last3Rows = Range("Q" & LastRow - 2, "S" & LastRow)
Last3Rows.Select
```

I am unable to proceed to autofill these values till row 37 since the last 3 cells' position vary for different worksheets.

The code I used to autofill from the dynamic ending was:

```
Last3Rows.Select
Range ("Q:S" & Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("Q18:S37").Select
```

Y is a column with values will row 37.
How can I proceed to autofill?

Comment: Why did you give a starting row to Q in the first but not to the second?

Comment: Please clarify; are you trying to copy the last 3 rows in Q - S on worksheet "Data", then paste in column Y row 37 on another worksheet or the same worksheet?

Comment: from the selection shown in the picture, i want to mimic the action of the mouse dragging it down until row 37

Comment: Did the answer i provided do what you wanted?

Comment: Do you simply need to copy formulas?

Comment: @GMalc It does not do what i wanted. Thx anyway

Comment: @AntiDrondert No, i dont want to copy formulas, but extrapolate the values down from the selection. Eg. when we have the numbers 1, 2, 3 and we want the numbering to continue until 20 so we select the 3 cells and we drag it down until excel autofills for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you din't use `.AutoFill` method in your example.
I hope I've understood what you asked:

```
LastRow = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Last3Rows = Range("Q" & LastRow - 2, "S" & LastRow)
Last3Rows.AutoFill Destination:=Last3Rows.Resize(37 - LastRow + Last3Rows.Rows.Count, 3)
```

Comment: Yes. This is what i wanted. works just fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a line of code that does what I think you are asking. The first part select the range you want to paste and the second part the range you want to copy from.

```
Sheets("Data").Range("Y37:AA39").Value = Range("Q" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Resize(3, 3).Value
```